# Tap gesture for navigation controller in iOS (MMDrawerController)

Tags: ios, swift, mmdrawercontroller

I am building an app for that I have used [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) as my slide navigation controller.

I have gone through their documentation but did not find any code specific to gestures as such. Can you help me out over here.

Comment: what you need to do more details please

Comment: ok so if slide view is open and I click on view of main controller the slide view should close.

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish ok so if slide view is open and I click on view of main controller the slide view should close.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your can add UITapGestureRecognizer to navigationBar with UIGestureRecognizerDelegate of gesture in controller.
   Overrive func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin, then calculator size than can executive tap gesture (ignore left, right bar item) -> Reture true
2. Custom title of navigationBar with:
   navigationItem.titleView = otherView
   and add action to this view